# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 not retrieving delete marked records from DBF

Tags: c#, oledb, dbf, dbase

I am using the following code to retrieve data from `DBF` file...

```
dbfConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=\"DBASE IV\";Data Source=" + appPath + "test\\sales\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM") + "\\";
OleDbConnection odconnection = new OleDbConnection(dbfConnectionString);
odconnection.Open();
OleDbCommand oCmdTest = new OleDbCommand("select  * from payment", odconnection);
oCmdTest.ExecuteNonQuery();
oledbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(oCmdTest);
oledbDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

This works fine except that it is not retrieving the records that are marked as deleted. I was able to successfully retrieve the deleted records  with `VFPOLEDB.1` as provider and executing some additional code  (`FoxPro` which is excellent but gives me some issues regarding the field formats :-`Error reading certain numeric values with VFPOLEDB driver` and this can be fixed by casting these fields but the problem is that my tables are too big so I have to figure out and  cast many fields )

```
OleDbCommand oCmdTest1 = new OleDbCommand("SET DELETED OFF", odconnection);
oCmdTest1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But this additional code wont work with `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`. How can I retrieve deleted records with `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` as provider from a `dbf` file ? Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: Try this and then do not use the modified OleDbCommand.     dbfConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=\"DBASE IV;Deleted=0\";Data Source=" + appPath + "test\\sales\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM") + "\\";

Comment: It's not working, But no errors..

Comment: Also tried with `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find a way to read deleted records with `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` or `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` from `DBF` files. But things worked like a charm when I used  a different provider, `Advantage OLE DB Provider`. Installed it and referenced the 32 bit `.dll` (Since my solution targets on `Any Cpu`). The connection string is modified in to..

```
dbfConnectionString = @"Provider=Advantage.OLEDB.1;User ID=adssys;Data Source=" + appPath + "test\\sales\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM") + "\\;TableType=ADS_CDX;ShowDeleted=TRUE;Advantage Server Type=ADS_LOCAL_SERVER;";
```

Here `ShowDeleted=TRUE` is used to include deleted records.